# Render template from twig extension

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, twig

I have built a twig extension to do some things and one of them is render a template. How can I access from inside the twig extension the engine environment and call the Render method?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can define the extension so that it needs the environment. Twig will automatically pass it to the function.

```
use Twig\Environment;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

public function getFunctions()
{
    return [
        new TwigFunction(
            'myfunction',
            [$this, 'myFunction'],
            ['needs_environment' => true]
        ),
    ];
}

public function myFunction(Environment $environment, string $someParam)
{
    // ...
}
```

## For older versions of Twig

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction(
            'myfunction',
            array($this, 'myFunction'),
            array('needs_environment' => true)
        ),
    );
}

public function myFunction(\Twig_Environment $environment, string $someParam)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: \Twig_Function_Method is deprecated, use \Twig_SimpleFunction

Answer (score 19):

Using this function the user can pass the twig environment instance to a twig extension

```
private $environment;

public function initRuntime(\Twig_Environment $environment)
{
    $this->environment = $environment;
}
```

Comment: Then do $this->environment->render()

Comment: initRuntime is now deprecated. The needs_environment by @tvlooy is the correct answer.

Answer (score 11):

@tvlooy answer give me a hint but didn't work for me. What I needed to to to achieve it is:

```
namespace AppBundle\Twig;


class MenuExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'menu_extension';
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
       return [
           new \Twig_SimpleFunction('myMenu', [$this, 'myMenu'], [
               'needs_environment' => true,
               'is_safe' => ['html']
           ])
       ];
    }

    public function myMenu(\Twig_Environment $environment)
    {
          return $environment->render('AppBundle:Menu:main-menu.html.twig');
    }
}
```

I needed addtionaly add `'is_safe' => ['html']` to avoid autoescaping of HTML.

I've also registered the class as symfony service:

```
app.twig.menu_extension:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\MenuExtension
    public: false
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

in TWIG template I've added `{{ myMenu() }}`

I work with `"twig/twig": "~1.10"`and Symfony 3.1.3 version

Comment: 'needs_environment' => true is the real deal here. +1

Answer (score 0):

If the problem persist even if you have set needs_environment parameter, you can use `row` in template when you call method like this :

```
{{ myMenu()|raw }}
```