# twig extension render html

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to create a twig function extension that render a twig template for a menu

```
/**
 * Return the functions registered as twig extensions
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('my_menu', array($this, 'myMenu')),
    );
}
```

my function

```
/** render a dropdown with link to conversation
 * @return string
 */
public function myMenu(\Twig_Environment $environment, $typeMenu, $menuId)
{

    return $environment->render('@menuDopdown.html.twig', array(
        'typeMenu' => $typeMenu,
    ));
}
```

but when i call the function i have a exeption for parametre 1

```
{{ my_menu(4,1280) }}
```

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   MenuBundle\Twig\TwigMenuExtension::myMenu() must be an instance of
>   Twig_Environment, integer given, called in
>   ...\app\cache\dev\twig\07\07a15176de77b3d862b64747d9728e117749b97e55d1082eb0f0eec4ffaf12d8.php
>   on line 164

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this function, before your myMenu function, so twig will automatically pass the environment

```
public function getFunctions()
{
return array(
    new \Twig_SimpleFunction(
        'myMenu',
        array($this, 'myMenu'),
        array('needs_environment' => true)
    ),
);
}
```

or check this link for more details [Render template from twig extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549026/render-template-from-twig-extension)